# How do I implement the [] operator for this structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, operators

I want to have something like this below:

```
template <class T>
struct Container{
 public:
  //[] operator
 private:
  T containment;
};
```

the containment is supposed to be an array with any selective number of dimensions as below:

```
Container<int[20][4]> obj;
Container<int[5][2][6]> obj1;
//etc...
```

And I want to implement the [] operator so that following assignments be possible:

```
obj[2][3]=6;
obj1[1][1][3]=3;
//etc...
```

But after a few tries I found myself stuck, how's that possible?

Comment: BTW, why do you need such a container? How about considering boost::array or boost::multi_array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who thought reference would come into play here? me!
Thanks to Niki Yoshiuchi, The answer in exact framework that I want is as it follows:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
struct Container {
private:
 T containment[N];
public:
 T & operator[](size_t index) { return containment[index]; }
};

Container<int[3][3][3],2> obj;
obj[1][1][1][1]=7;
```

Comment: If that does everything you want, then great

Comment: Oh, that's not what I was chasing after, this doesn't perform bound checking at all levels, only the first, since afterward you've got a mere array. By the way, for ease of use, you could extract the first dimension with a helper I think.

Comment: The helper might look like this: `template <class T> struct remove_dimension; template <class T, size_t N> struct remove_dimension<T[N]> { typedef T type;};` and the operator as `typename remove_dimension<T>::type& operator[](size_t index)`

Comment: @UncleBens: thanks for standing in, I admit I got a bit lazy there :)

Answer (score 5):

Your subscription operator should return a proxy object, which would itself implement a subscription operator.

If we decompose the call to `obj[2][3] = 6` this would yield:

- `obj[2]` --> proxy object
- `obj[2][6]` --> reference to `int`

By looking at `obj1` you'll realize that all but the last `[]` should return a proxy object.

This is typically down by using a templated proxy, with a "depth" parameter, and specialize it for the suitable depth. In your case, your proxy will have a pointer to `T` for the first element it might yield, as well as the list of dimensions (as template parameters).

It isn't trivial though, because you wish for an arbitrary number of parameters it seems. Depending on whether or not your targetted compiler supports variadic templates you may be in for some grief indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it something like this (new template for each dimensionality though).

```
template <class T, size_t m, size_t n>
struct Container{
 public:
  int& operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
  {
      return containment[i][j];
  }

 private:
  T containment[m][n];
};

Container<int, 3, 4> ints;
ints(0,3) = 5;
```

Or you could use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html), and save a lot of pain.

> The Boost MultiArray library enhances
>   the C++ standard containers with
>   versatile multi-dimensional array
>   abstractions. It includes a general
>   array class template and native array
>   adaptors that support idiomatic array
>   operations and interoperate with C++
>   Standard Library containers and
>   algorithms. The arrays share a common
>   interface, expressed as a generic
>   programming in terms of which generic
>   array algorithms can be implemented.

Comment: one issue with this design is that each template should have a new name, because you cannot specialize with a different arity. A common solution is to have dummy parameters (with default values). Good call about Boost.MultiArray, apart from exercising one self, it's best to reuse existing solutions :)

Comment: @Matthieu - yes, also this does not allow `operator[][]` notation without more work.  I could probably tolerate the pain of `Array2D`, `Array3D` etc.  How could I tolerate the pain of not using `Boost.MultiArray` though, knowing it's there?

Comment: As I said in my previous, unless coding for an exercise, there's no point in reinventing the wheel, which is I upvoted this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is in know the return type of `operator[]`.  You could try something like this:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
struct Container {
T containment[N];
T &operator[](size_t index) { return containment[index]; }
};

Container<int[2][6], 5> obj;
```

Alternatively you could define Container in terms of itself:

```
Container<Container<Container<int[6]>[2]>[5]> obj;
```

Comment: _Did you compile it? It doesn't work, return type can't be an array.

Comment: _But return type can be a reference to array, check my answer ;) .

Comment: Ah right, forgot about that.  I'm going to edit the code so it returns a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The basics of making an n-dimensional collection would be something like this. It assumes the container cannot be redimensioned.

```
template< typename T >
class MultiDimContainer
{
   std::vector<size_t> dims;

   std::vector<T> data;

public:
   MultiDimContainer( const std::vector<size_t> dims )
   {
       // work out the product of dims and set data to that size
   }

   T& at( const std::vector<size_t> & dim )
   {
      // calculate where it lives in memory and return that element
   }
};
```

As I have implemented at() to take a single parameter you can use operator[] for this. You would probably want 2 overloads, one const and one non-const, and at() would bounds check whilst operator[] would not. You would probably want one helper (non-template) function to calculate the location of this element in your data vector.

Of course, constructing the vector is a multi-step process so you could use some magic class to construct one.

You could also have operator[] for your container would take a single size_t and would return a ContainerReferencer object. This is not a real multi-dimensional array but a slice to data held elsewhere. Once again there could be const or non-const versions.

Getting multiple calls of operator[] to filter down to the T value_type or a reference to it is not possible using this model.

It would be possible using a hard-dimensioned array which could be a template parameter. So if you know it is 4-dimensions you would call it

MultiDimCollection< double, 4>

and it would always have 4 dimensions. You can then get operator[] to return a MultiDimCollectionReference< double, 3 >

this would go down to 2 and 1 (a vector) then that would be specialised to return a scalar.